# Sum of distinct irrational numbers could be an integer?

Tags: number-theory

I'm wondering if there exist two distinct irrational numbers whose sum (subtraction) is an integer number. I've thought with this example but I don't know if it is correct:
$$3.14159265...-0.14159265...=3$$

Comment: Your answer is correct but imprecise since you did not clearly specify which irrational number $3.14159265\dots$ and $0.14159265\dots$ are.  It is clear from context that you intend these to be $\pi$ and $\pi-3$ respectively, but this should have been clearly specified.

Comment: Note that $(1+\pi) + (1-\pi)=2$, and $(\pi+1) - (\pi-1) =2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:  $a = 10 - \sqrt{3}$ and $b = \sqrt{3}$.

What is $a+b$?

Answer (score 1):

Your example, once you use $\pi$ and $\pi-3$ instead of the decimals, is correct and indicates many more examples.  Pick your favorite irrational $r$.  Then $r+(n-r)=n$, so if $n$ is an integer you are there.  Because the rationals are closed under addition/subtraction you know $n-r$ is irrational.  Were it rational, $n-(n-r)=r$ would be rational as well.